# Laravel 9.5.1 Undefined Variable on return view

Tags: laravel

Good day, I'm having a problem on passing data from controller to the blade.

This is the code from controller:

```
function dashboard(){
        $adminData = ['LoggedAdminInfo'=>Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first()];
        $sensor_latest_data = array('list'=>DB::table('sensors')->latest('id')->first());
        $sensor_data = Sensor::select('id', 'created_at')->get()->groupBy(function($data) {
            return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('M');
        });
        return view('admin.index', $adminData, $sensor_latest_data, ['chart_data'=>$sensor_data]);
    }
```

[image]

The other data is working fine except for the last argument on return view.

I tried putting it inside the compact() function and it returned this:
 `return view('admin.index', $adminData, $sensor_latest_data, compact(['chart_data'=>$sensor_data]));`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact function gets the variable name from string and map it to an array. For exmaple if you use compact('test'), it will search for test variable and map it and return it as ['test' => $test]

```
return view('admin.index', ['adminData' => $adminData, 'sensor_latest_data' => $sensor_latest_data, 'chart_data'=>$sensor_data]);
```

or just change your function to :

```
function dashboard(){
    $adminData = ['LoggedAdminInfo'=>Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first()];
    $sensor_latest_data = array('list'=>DB::table('sensors')->latest('id')->first());
    $chart_data = Sensor::select('id', 'created_at')->get()->groupBy(function($data) {
        return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('M');
    });
    return view('admin.index', compact('adminData', 'sensor_latest_data', 'chart_data'));
}
```

and here is simplified version:

```
function dashboard(){
    $LoggedAdminInfo = Admin::where('id','=',session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
    $list = DB::table('sensors')->latest('id')->first();
    $chart_data = Sensor::select('id', 'created_at')->get()->groupBy(function($data) {
        return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('M');
    });

    return view('admin.index', compact('LoggedAdminInfo', 'list', 'chart_data'));
}
```

Comment: I think the $sensor_latest_data is affected if I use the second code you provided, it shows undefined $list variable from the index.blade.

Comment: Since, I don't know your view I can't say anything about it but I guess you got the point of compact or sending data to your view. Do not forget to mark my answer as correct if it is worked for you. I updated my answer to work directly.

Comment: In view I'm using this the get the data from controller:
 $soil_type  =    $list -> soilType;

 $ph         =    $list -> ph;

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views here you can read more about the passing variables to a view.

Comment: Thank you, now its working using your simplified version.
And also thanks for the link, Ill read it for more info.